# Can't make folder in Android

Tags: android

I try to create a folder in internal Storage of android, but I can't.

The folder was not created, but I don't received any issue in thelogcat.

In the first time, I'm using a libreary for create/modify files/folders:
[sromku - android-simple-storage](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-storage)

After I'm try directly with Android API, with same problem.

**CODES:**

```
    //USING ANDROID API
    String intStorageDirectory = getFilesDir().toString();
    File folder = new File(intStorageDirectory, "SUPERPLUS");
    folder.mkdirs();

    //USING library
    //Get internal Storage
    Storage storage = SimpleStorage.getInternalStorage(this);
    // create directory
    storage.createDirectory("SUPERPLUS",true);
```

The folder should be created in "/storage/emulated/0" ,no?

Comment: for `storage/emulated/0` use `getExternalStorageDirectory()`

Comment: 'folder.mkdirs();'. Do not blindly call mkdirs. First use exists() to see if the folder exists. And if you call mkdirs then check ifs return value as it can fail to make the directory. If it returns false display a Toast telling the user this and then return inmediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getFilesDir()` returns path that is private to app. You can't access it directly using any File Manager. Something like below

```
data/data/yourpackagename/
```

If you want to create folder on storage that will be accessible by `File Manager` then you should use `getExternalStorageDirectory()`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like...

```
//this is root path of your folder
 String ROOT_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

 //this is your folder

String my_folder = ROOT_PATH + File.separator "nameOfFolder/";
```